# How to get image 50% centered ontop of element

Tags: html, css

How is this possible?
https://gyazo.com/ef7b3c65b3b5e09906c01edcc7143c86¨

I want to develop a phone app, and this design looks awesome, but I can't figure out how to do the centered button? Any tips on how to start?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
plus {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

html ex:

```
<div class="panel">...</div>
<a class="plus" href="#plus"></a>
```

or use as display: inline-block and set text-align: center to parent div.
Also you can use:
if button width 250px - use 125px

```
position: absolute; 
bottom: 10px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -125px;
```